# How to determinate $K$ in this probability density function?

Tags: calculus, probability, functions, definite-integrals

$1)$ Determine $k$

$2)$ Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$

$$f(X)=\begin{cases} KX & 0\le X <2 \\ K(4-X) & 2 \le X \le 4 \\0 & o.w. \end{cases}$$

Comment: @LeilaHatami And yet another useless edit to a 3+ years old question. Well done.

Comment: @Did Sure you cannot find more productive ways of contributing to the site?

Answer (score 2):

For **any** density function $f(x)$, we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=1.$$
In our particular case, the integral is equal to
$$\int_0^2 kx\,dx +\int_2^4 k(4-x)\,dx.$$

Integrate. The first integral is $2k$. The second integral is also $2k$.

**Another way:** An alternate way to calculate $k$in this case is to draw the density function. For the non-zero part, we get a triangle with base $4$ and height $2k$, and therefore area $4k$. This area must  be $1$.

For the **expectation**, we need to calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx.$$
If we really want to integrate, break up the integral into two parts, $0$ to $2$ and $2$ to $4$.

However, in this case, we do not need to integrate. The density function is **symmetric** about $x=2$, so the mean is $2$.